# Saving all the values from a tableview to an array in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I had an application in which I am using 4 sections for a `UITableView`. Each cell I had some calculations and displaying the value. After displaying I need the values of section 2,3,4 needs to be saved to core data and taken back.

I had considered this sections separate while doing the calculations so each case I considered as different. Now I need to save all these data from different sections of `UITableView` on to core data. Can anybody point me how I can achieve that?

Comment: I would suggest you to calculate those values before populate to user interface so this way to don't have to recalculate over and over when each cell is loading and easier to save in core data back.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is stored in each cell individually, you'll have to loop through each section to get all data. Here's an eample

```
- (NSArray *)getAllTableData {
NSMutableArray *allData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//Loop through sections
for (int section=0;section<self.tableView.numberOfSections;section++) {

    //Loop through rows
    for (int row=0;row<[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];row++) {
        //Get the cell
        UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];

        //Get the data (this is adding the text label)
        [allData addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    }
}
return allData;
```

}

In the future, you should store data in an array while calculations are completing.